# Spring-boot rest api current request is not multipart request with postman

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot

I'm having an issue with using Postman to call an API within my spring-boot application.

Error `Current request is not a multipart request`

Postman:
[Postman screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7mHb.png)
Most other posts are fixed by people removing the header, which is not something that's worked from me.

Here's my controller:

```
@Controller
public class RestController {

    @GetMapping("/upload/remote")
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleFileUploadRemote(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

This returns null just for testing purposes.

I've tried leaving it as `@RequestMapping("/upload/remote")` as well.
Any ideas on what could be going wrong here? I've left out a lot of logic for testing this error.

**UPDATE 1:**
I tried using `RequestPart("file")` instead of `RequestParam("file")` as well as turning `GetMapping` into `RequestMapping` and `PostMapping` with the above changes. I still get the same error, however, with PostMapping I get the following: `Request method 'GET' not supported`

Edit: 
Here's the code that I see if I click the "code" option within Postman:

```
POST /upload/remote HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 30b67342-6e38-4f2e-8335-fb118d28bf50
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="C:\settings.xml


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Comment: Can you share the latest postman screenshot after you convert your Mapping handler to POST in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try using, `@RequestPart` instead of `@RequestParam` and normally such methods are POST. So try using

```
@PostMapping("/upload/remote")
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleFileUploadRemote(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: When I do this I get the error ```Request method 'GET' not supported```. I also tried this leaving it as ```@GetMapping``` and ```@RequestMapping``` and get the same error I mentioned in the above post about the multipart request.

Comment: @gprice, Check whether you chose the post method in postman and postmapping in code

Comment: @Prashanth There's a link to my postman screenshot above, using Post. When I have ```@PostMapping``` and double check that postman is doing a post, I get the following: ```Request method 'GET' not supported```

Comment: Request method 'GET' not supported error only comes if you send the GET request and there are no GET handlers in your controller.

Comment: @Prashanth according to another users' post: "method = POST will work if you 'post' a form to the url /test.

if you type a url in address bar of a browser and hit enter, it's always a GET request, so you had to specify POST request.

Google for HTTP GET and HTTP POST (there are several others like PUT DELETE). They all have their own meaning."

Comment: Thanks, @gprice11, But I have googled these long years before.

Comment: @gprice11 , can you add your code into github? I would like to execute

Comment: @gprice11 Did the issue get resolved? Any updates?

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ""/upload/remote"", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void fileUplaod(MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request) {

    return null;
}
```